# how to get same date all records in between two dates without using time in mysql

Tags: mysql

//Query

```
 SELECT a.amount,a.date,c.acc_id,'cash_chq_rec'
    FROM tb_cash_chq_receipt a,
         tb_chart_of_account c
    WHERE a.cr_acc_id = 1 AND a.cr_acc_id = c.acc_id AND a.date >= '2016-12-09' 
          AND a.date <= '2016-12-10'

    UNION

    SELECT b.amount,b.date,c.acc_id,'cash_chq_paid'
    FROM tb_cash_chq_paid b,
         tb_chart_of_account c
    WHERE b.dr_acc_id = 1 AND b.dr_acc_id = c.acc_id AND b.date >= '2016-12-09' 
          AND b.date <= '2016-12-10'
    ORDER BY DATE
```

//Table

```
2016-12-09 1032 record1
2016-12-09 1033 record2
2016-12-09 1034 record3
```

Im trying this query but getting only one record but i want three of them.

Comment: give some more sample data

Comment: use union all instead of union

Comment: First: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it. Second: what is the result of each individual select ?

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  a.amount,
  a.date,
  c.acc_id,
  'cash_chq_rec'
FROM
  tb_cash_chq_receipt a,
  tb_chart_of_account c
WHERE
  a.cr_acc_id = 1 AND a.cr_acc_id = c.acc_id AND DATE(a.date) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2016-12-09','%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2016-12-10','%Y-%m-%d') //Change This line used BETWEEN Function
UNION
SELECT
  b.amount,
  b.date,
  c.acc_id,
  'cash_chq_paid'
FROM
  tb_cash_chq_paid b,
  tb_chart_of_account c
WHERE
  b.dr_acc_id = 1 AND b.dr_acc_id = c.acc_id AND Date(B.date) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2016-12-09','%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2016-12-10','%Y-%m-%d')

ORDER BY DATE
```

Try this one.
Hopes this will helps you.

Comment: please include some explanation of what you change and how solve it.

Comment: Instead of > and < operator you may try `BETWEEN` function for Date and Timestamp field. Also if you want to exclude time fraction from your TIMESTAMP field  ,you need to cast that column to `DATE` Using `DATE` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help guys but there was a mistake, i was doing union so getting merge records that's why query was converting my data into union like

columnA | columnB | columnC
abcd    | abcd    | 2017-02-09
abcd    | abcd    | 2017-02-09

it will obviously show only abcd one record.

But if data would be 
columnA | columnB | columnC
abcd    | abcd    | 2017-02-09
abcd    | abcc    | 2017-02-09

it will show both records.
Thanks.